# Process and AppDomain load/unload

Tags: c#, .net, process, appdomain

If I instance a new Process in which I then create a new AppDomain, I'm wondering what is the safest way to end the Process. Should I:

1. AppDomain.Unload(myAppDomain)
2. Process.Close()   OR Process.Dispose(), then Process.Close()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no need to unload your domain manually before closing the process. And you should call only Process.Close().